# PHP to use WSDL from local Windows Service

Tags: php, wsdl

I have a windows service stored locally on my computer. The services are specified through an WSDL interface. How can I access these methods from the local stored windows service on my website through PHP?

I looked and looked but can't find any documentation on how to use PHP with WSDL.

I'm not sure I understood this whole cycle correct as well. As I understand it:

I have a local stored windows service. 
It has some methods, which are accessible through WSDL for web purpose. 
I can then use PHP to work with WSDL to access these methods and use them on my website.

Is this understood correct?

This is the part of my wsdl I want to access:
 `<wsdl:operation name="GetStudyData">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IKPIntegrationServices/GetStudyData" message="tns:IKPIntegrationServices_GetStudyData_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IKPIntegrationServices/GetStudyDataResponse" message="tns:IKPIntegrationServices_GetStudyData_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>`

I want to show this data that comes from "GetStudyData" on my webpage through php somehow.

Comment: WSDL is most commonly used for Soap services. Read up on PHP's [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) (you might need to manually install the soap-extension for PHP).

Comment: I actually already read that through, what I can't seem to find anywhere is some documentation of how to interact with the WSDL.  My service has a function that I want to use on my website, but I have no idea what the syntax etc is to use this function inside of PHP.  Did that make sense?

Comment: Seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35604529/296555