# consuming a java soap wep service using php web application

Tags: java, php, exchangewebservices

I'm building a soap web service using Java for bank payment methods, and I'd like to know how can I use or consume this web service in another web application create with php as a e-commerce web site to use these methods for payment.

Answer (score 0):

There are three method to consuming web service (Soap) using php client, please refer to the below link:

[Consuming web service (Soap) using php client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184674/consuming-web-service-soap-using-php-client)